# D3 in vscode webviews, can't see anything

Tags: node.js, typescript, d3.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do a hello world example with d3 just to see if I can use the library. To this effect I copied [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1300016) ultraminimialistic example into vscodes webview example.

This gave me the following code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const vscode = require("vscode");
const d3 = require("d3");

function activate(context) {
    // Create and show a new webview
    const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('catCoding', // Identifies the type of the webview. Used internally
    'Cat Coding', // Title of the panel displayed to the user
    vscode.ViewColumn.One, // Editor column to show the new webview panel in.
    {} // Webview options. More on these later.
    );
    panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();

    d3.select(panel.document).append("span").text("Hello, world!");

    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('catCoding.start', () => {
    }));
}

exports.activate = activate;

function getWebviewContent() {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Cat Coding</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    d3.select("body").append("span")
        .text("Hello, world!");

    </script>
  </body>
  </html>`;
}
// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() { }
exports.deactivate = deactivate;
//# sourceMappingURL=extension.js.map
```

My expectation was to see a hello world just like int he example, but I see this instead:
[image]

There are no alert messages, the problems, output and debug consoles are all fine and even the chrome dev console reports no errors. I am stuck.

There's 2 different attempts at using d3 in here, they both fail, one uses JS directly, the other uses HTML.

Comment: you need to load the D3 script files from the extension via a URI, enable JS for the Webview, use Content security policy and use D3v5 or later, D3v3 is really old

Comment: Let me edit this because I realize this can be a little confusing. I am not just trying to do it with the link on the html body, I am also trying to use d3 locally through npm, both methods fail.